# How to open another tab inside previous tab?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have three pages. Let's suppose,

1. One page i.e Parent page is written in JS and html
2. The second page is in html and angular js
3. Third page is similar to parent page but with another set of data.

So the problem is when the user will click on one hyper link it will open the second page and respective data will be displayed. Now on the second page one button is there so when it will be clicked it should open tab in parents window. not as another new window or new tab. It will be new tab but under parents page.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thank that is directly possible (yet) in browsers.
What you could do is somehow send a request from the page on which the button is clicked to the next tab and that might work. But it's something that I have never seen before and can't directly answer.

Comment: thank you for you response and yes completely agree with you but next tab is not we need , its like concept of webtop , windows under windows . I have no idea but anyway much appreciated